# Splunk query does not return multiple instances of the field values

Tags: xml, splunk-query

I have a Splunk query that identifies all of the fields extracted from the xml file but not all of the instances of the data.
There is a huge xml file that has multiple instances of the result but only identifies 1 result in the field list.
This is the query:

```
source="service.log" sourcetype="dispatchapp" "<billingMethod>RULE</billingMethod>" "createMessage MsgSource" "<purchCostReference>2618252</purchCostReference>" "<eventType>DISPATCH</eventType>" | xmlkv
```

This is the result:
[image]

The highlighted fields are the ones I am interested in.  There are 3 carrier tags and many ns:numberCodes.  But it is only showing 1.
Below is the xml that has the data

```
<purchasedCost>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2618252</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>NS</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53RP</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4061</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>NSAU</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>6300 SOUTH INDIANA AVENUE</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:city>CHICAGO</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>IL</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>60637</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>CST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </origin>
         <destination>
            <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>CROX</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>NORFOLK SOUTHERN RAILROAD</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:address2>125 COUNTY ROAD</ns2:address2>
            <ns2:city>CROXTON</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>NJ</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>07307</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>EST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </destination>
         <stopOff>
            <ns2:stopOffLocation>
               <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
               <ns2:locAbbr>CROX</ns2:locAbbr>
               <ns2:address1>NORFOLK SOUTHERN RAILROAD</ns2:address1>
               <ns2:address2>125 COUNTY ROAD</ns2:address2>
               <ns2:city>CROXTON</ns2:city>
               <ns2:stateProvince>NJ</ns2:stateProvince>
               <ns2:postalCode>07307</ns2:postalCode>
               <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
               <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
               <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>EST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
               <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-20T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
         <actualDispatchDate>2020-05-21T08:20:53.000Z</actualDispatchDate>
         <estimatedArrivalDate>2020-05-25T08:18:53.000Z</estimatedArrivalDate>
         <billingMethod>LOCAL</billingMethod>
         <STCCCode>4711110</STCCCode>
         <planNumber>065</planNumber>
         <powerType>1X</powerType>
         <powerOnlyFlag>false</powerOnlyFlag>
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2618252</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>BNSF</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53RP</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4022</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>BNSF</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>3770 EAST WASHINGTON AVENUE</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:city>LOS ANGELES</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>CA</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>90040</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>PST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </origin>
         <destination>
            <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>CROX</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>NORFOLK SOUTHERN RAILROAD</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:address2>125 COUNTY ROAD</ns2:address2>
            <ns2:city>CROXTON</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>NJ</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>07307</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>EST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </destination>
         <stopOff>
            <ns2:stopOffLocation>
               <ns2:numberCode>9996</ns2:numberCode>
               <ns2:stateProvince>DU</ns2:stateProvince>
               <ns2:postalCode>00000</ns2:postalCode>
               <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
               <ns2:numberType>1</ns2:numberType>
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-20T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
         <actualDispatchDate>2020-05-21T08:20:53.000Z</actualDispatchDate>
         <estimatedArrivalDate>2020-05-25T08:19:53.000Z</estimatedArrivalDate>
         <billingMethod>RULE</billingMethod>
         <STCCCode>4711110</STCCCode>
         <planNumber>065</planNumber>
         <powerType>1X</powerType>
         <powerOnlyFlag>false</powerOnlyFlag>
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2618252</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>NS</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53RP</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4061</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>NSAU</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>6300 SOUTH INDIANA AVENUE</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:city>CHICAGO</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>IL</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>60637</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>CST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </origin>
         <destination>
            <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
            <ns2:locAbbr>CROX</ns2:locAbbr>
            <ns2:address1>NORFOLK SOUTHERN RAILROAD</ns2:address1>
            <ns2:address2>125 COUNTY ROAD</ns2:address2>
            <ns2:city>CROXTON</ns2:city>
            <ns2:stateProvince>NJ</ns2:stateProvince>
            <ns2:postalCode>07307</ns2:postalCode>
            <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
            <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
            <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>EST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
            <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
         </destination>
         <stopOff>
            <ns2:stopOffLocation>
               <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
               <ns2:locAbbr>CROX</ns2:locAbbr>
               <ns2:address1>NORFOLK SOUTHERN RAILROAD</ns2:address1>
               <ns2:address2>125 COUNTY ROAD</ns2:address2>
               <ns2:city>CROXTON</ns2:city>
               <ns2:stateProvince>NJ</ns2:stateProvince>
               <ns2:postalCode>07307</ns2:postalCode>
               <ns2:locType>FDEG</ns2:locType>
               <ns2:numberType>8</ns2:numberType>
               <ns2:timeZoneAbbr>EST</ns2:timeZoneAbbr>
               <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-20T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
         <actualDispatchDate>2020-05-21T08:20:53.000Z</actualDispatchDate>
         <estimatedArrivalDate>2020-05-25T08:20:53.000Z</estimatedArrivalDate>
         <billingMethod>LOCAL</billingMethod>
         <STCCCode>4711110</STCCCode>
         <planNumber>065</planNumber>
         <powerType>1X</powerType>
         <powerOnlyFlag>false</powerOnlyFlag>
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
   </purchasedCost>
```

How to extract the numberCode and carrier instances for each of the purchase cost segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to get multiple instances of a value in an xml file...

You can tell `rex` to return both of them using the `max_match` option.

```
| rex max_match=0 "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<origin>[^\<]+)"
| eval originCode = mvindex(origin, 0), destCode = mvindex(origin, 1)
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to know the order of the matches so this fails if destination precedes origin in the XML.

You should be able to use `spath` to extract the entire XML and refer to "origin.numberCode" and "destination.numberCode", but I don't have enough experience with that command to offer much guidance.